# Deploy .net application with cygwin

Tags: .net, cygwin, portability

I need to use one of the commands of cygwin (readelf) . I use that command on my .net c# console application. How will I be able to deploy my application making it eassy for the users to install it. I dont want to have the users have to install cygwin in order to use my program. Maybe I could perform a silent instal or even beter use cygwin libraries and call them from my code. I dont know if that will be posible.

Comment: Saw [>this<](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575348/is-there-an-open-source-library-to-read-elf-files-in-net) Maybe it can help.

Comment: I tried that and that does not give me the debug (dwarf) info that I need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are deploying an application that depends on cygwin that is probably because you need it's functionality not the linux like terminal that cygwin offers. To get the reaadele functionality it may be downloaded from [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/binutils/binutils-2.22/binutils-2.22-1-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma/). to use it just pass the same parameters that you will us on linux. If you are interested on using other linux commands you should try [this other](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-command-line-utilities-for-windows/).